# Redirection issue on Symfony 5

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I try to publish a symfony application on an web server.

The structure of the webserver is :

```
www
    gpexe
        config
        public
        src
        var
        templates
        tests
        vendor
```

I've setup an htaccess on the root folder `www`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gpexe/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gpexe/public/$1 [L]
```

And there's also an htaccess on the public folder generated by Symfony avaliable [here](https://gist.github.com/alch/7766993).

I managed to access to the main page when typing the root address ([www.gpexe.fr](http://www.gpexe.fr)), but the css and js link are redirected correctly, for instance :

```
No route found for "GET /build/login.css"
```

This because the address /build/login.css must be replaced by /gpexe/public/build/login.css to be usable.

I also try to validate the root htaccess on [this website](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and the address /build/login.css is well rewrited by /gpexe/public/build/login.css.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: can you create a symbolic link from public/index.php into www folder named index.php, i think this work normally

Comment: So I create a symlink to `gpexe/public/index.php` into folder `www` named `index.php`. This is not helpful. I still have the same issue.
The only way to slove the problem is to declare in Encore config a public path as `/gpexe/public/build`